# Java 8 Date/Time (JSR-310) types mapping with Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: java, java-8, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, java-time

I have simple document with Java 8 date/time fields

```
@Document
public class Token {
    private Instant createdAt;
    ...
}
```

that I want to persist with Spring Data MongoDB version 1.5. But fields of type `java.time.Instant` could not be de-serialized correctly because `MappingMongoConverter` lacks converters for `java.time` classes.

In Spring 4 I found `org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.DateTimeConverters` with different `Converter`s including `InstantToLongConverter` and `LongToInstantConverter` declared as private static classes.

How can I configure `MongoTemplate` to use them to map `Instant` fields to longs?

Comment: can you please post the exception stack trace?

Comment: Create StackOverflow example to replicate behavior https://github.com/firefoxNX/Java8DateTimeMapToSpringDataMongo

Comment: Stack trace https://gist.github.com/Happy-Neko/7d8e62141a32864400b0

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best way but I added Java 8 Date/Time (JSR-310) types support to Spring Data MongoDB `1.5.0.RELEASE` like this:

1. First step. Add simple Spring `Converter`s

   ```
   public class InstantToLongConverter implements Converter<Instant, Long> {
       @Override
       public Long convert(Instant instant) {
           return instant.toEpochMilli();
       }
   }

   public class LongToInstantConverter implements Converter<Long, Instant> {
       @Override
       public Instant convert(Long source) {
           return Instant.ofEpochMilli(source);
       }
   }

   public class LocalDateToStringConverter implements Converter<LocalDate, String> {
       @Override
       public String convert(LocalDate localDate) {
           return localDate.toString();
       }
   }

   public class StringToLocalDateConverter implements Converter<String, LocalDate> {
       @Override
       public LocalDate convert(String source) {
           return LocalDate.parse(source);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Second step. Register these custom `Converter`s with `MappingMongoConverter` in your `AbstractMongoConfiguration` implementation like this:

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"my.app.repository"})
   public class MongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

       ...

       @Override
       public CustomConversions customConversions() {
           return new CustomConversions(Arrays.asList(
                   new InstantToLongConverter(), new LongToInstantConverter(),
                   new LocalDateToStringConverter(), new StringToLocalDateConverter()));
       }
   }
   ```

Now your document's `Instant` fields will be persisted as long values and `LocalDate`s as Strings.

Comment: I am still getting org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingException: No property null found on entity class java.time.Instant to bind constructor parameter to! Can you please check the github project I have updated with the converter's you mentioned.

Comment: Try adding @ComponentScan(basePackages = "stackoverflow.java8mongo")
 annotation to Application class

Comment: But this coverters are already provided by spring since spring version 4.0.1. See `org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.DateTimeConverters`

Comment: These converters are mentioned in the question. But as of `spring-data-mongodb-1.6.1.RELEASE` they are still not registered for Mongo type mapping.

Comment: By the way. If you want to use this converters check first this answer to save you  work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32507470/unable-to-find-org-springframework-format-datetime-standard-datetimeconverters/32510002#32510002

Answer (score 3):

@user882209 explained it all just perfectly.
Since Spring Data MongoDB 1.7 the support for JSR-310 has been added.
If application is backed by Spring Boot every version over 1.2.8 would contain it as well.
In a Spring Boot-ed app you can just do it the following:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoDbConfig {

    @Autowired
    private MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory;

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() {
        MappingMongoConverter converter = new MappingMongoConverter(new DefaultDbRefResolver(mongoDbFactory),
            new MongoMappingContext());
        converter.setCustomConversions(new CustomConversions(Arrays.asList(...)));

    return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory, converter);
    }
}
```

The following converters are provided by the **`Jsr310Converters`** class:
`DateToLocalDateTimeConverter - LocalDateTimeToDateConverter
DateToLocalDateConverter - LocalDateToDateConverter
DateToLocalTimeConverter - LocalTimeToDateConverter
DateToInstantConverter - InstantToDateConverter`

Comment: If you extend your config from `AbstractMongoConfiguration` you can even spare the `mongoTemplate` bean and all available converters are registered.