# Unable to find org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.DateTimeConverters

Tags: java, spring, maven, converters

There is a Spring class, `org.springframework.format.datetime.standard.DateTimeConverters`, with some useful converters, that I am not able to find. It is documented in the [4.1.0.RC1_to_4.1.0.RC2](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.0.RC1_to_4.1.0.RC2/Spring%20Framework%204.1.0.RC2/org/springframework/format/datetime/standard/DateTimeConverters.html)  javadoc but not in the [4.1.0.RELEASE](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/datetime/standard/package-summary.html). Note the `@UsesJava8` annotation in the javadoc. Of course I am using Java 8 as I need to convert between the new types.

The class has its source code in [GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/4.1.x/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/format/datetime/standard/DateTimeConverters.java) with the 4.1 tag and I add the project by Maven using the following xml to my pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Were the converters moved to another package? Where can I find them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `spring-context` artifact in version 4.2.1 contains the `DateTimeConverters` class, as can be seen in the [GitHub repo](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.2.1.RELEASE/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/format/datetime/standard/DateTimeConverters.java).

Note however that it is a package class, it is not part of the public API and that's why this class is not visible in the online Javadoc. `javadoc`, by default, does not generate HTML pages for package classes; [quoting its reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#CHDEEFJD) (emphasis mine):

> The javadoc command parses the declarations and documentation comments in a set of Java source files and produces a corresponding set of HTML pages that describe (by default) the **public and protected classes, nested classes (but not anonymous inner classes), interfaces, constructors, methods, and fields.**

And if you're really curious, you can see that Spring keeps the default values during Javadoc generation, by looking at their [`build.gradle`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/v4.2.1.RELEASE/build.gradle#L240-L253).

If you're using Java 8, Spring automatically registers those converters with the following XML declaration:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven conversion-service="conversionService"/>

<bean id="conversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean" />
```

Comment: I assume that I can only use the converters globally. To choose the conversion case by case would need the @Convert which has to access the class. 

Thanks you for everything.