# Register a new Date Converter Auditable in Spring Data MongoDB for ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I want my auditable (`@CreatedDate` and `@LastModifiedDate`) MongoDB document to work with `ZonedDateTime` fields.

Apparently this type is not supported by Spring Data (have a look at `org.springframework.data.auditing.AnnotationAuditingMetadata`).

Framework version: **Spring Boot 2.0.0** and **Spring Data MongoDB 2.0.0**

#### Spring Data auditing error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid date type for member <MEMBER NAME>!
Supported types are [org.joda.time.DateTime, org.joda.time.LocalDateTime, java.util.Date, java.lang.Long, long].
```

#### Mongo configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableMongoAuditing
public class MongoConfiguration {

}
```

#### The auditable entity:

```java
public abstract class BaseDocument {

    @CreatedDate
    private ZonedDateTime createdDate;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private ZonedDateTime lastModifiedDate;

}
```

### Things I tried

I also tried creating a custom converter for `ZonedDateTime`, but it is not considered by Spring Data. The class `DateConvertingAuditableBeanWrapper` has a `ConversionService` which is configured in the constructor method with `JodaTimeConverters`, `Jsr310Converters` and `ThreeTenBackPortConverters`.

#### Custom converter:

```java
@Component
public class LocalDateTimeToZonedDateTimeConverter implements Converter<LocalDateTime, ZonedDateTime> {

    @Override
    public ZonedDateTime convert(LocalDateTime source) {
        return source.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    }

}
```

#### Spring Data DateConvertingAuditableBeanWrapper:

```java
class DefaultAuditableBeanWrapperFactory implements AuditableBeanWrapperFactory {

    abstract static class DateConvertingAuditableBeanWrapper implements AuditableBeanWrapper {

        private final ConversionService conversionService;

    }
}
```

Is it possible to audit `ZonedDateTime` fields?

How can I register a converter?

Comment: This answer will not work because Spring Data Auditing uses its own converters, not the ones registered in `MappingMongoConverter` [Java 8 Date/Time (JSR-310) types mapping with Spring Data MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23972002/java-8-date-time-jsr-310-types-mapping-with-spring-data-mongodb?rq=1)

Comment: It works, since when value type is same as the target type, no need convert, so you can create your datetimeprovider to generate a ZonedDateTime for auditing, I tried it works

Answer (score 23):

Create a [`DateTimeProvider`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/auditing/DateTimeProvider.html) to provide the current time to be used when auditing:

```java
@Component("dateTimeProvider")
public class CustomDateTimeProvider implements DateTimeProvider {
    
    @Override
    public Optional<TemporalAccessor> getNow() {
        return Optional.of(ZonedDateTime.now());
    }
}
```

And then:

- Reference the [`DateTimeProvider`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/auditing/DateTimeProvider.html) component in the [`@EnableMongoAuditing`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/config/EnableMongoAuditing.html) annotation;
- Create [`Converter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter.html)s for [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html);
- Add the [`Converter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/Converter.html) instances to a [`MongoCustomConversions`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/convert/MongoCustomConversions.html) instance;
- Expose the [`MongoCustomConversions`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/convert/MongoCustomConversions.html) instance as a [`@Bean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html).

```java
@Configuration
@EnableMongoAuditing(dateTimeProviderRef = "dateTimeProvider")
public class MongoConfiguration {
    
    @Bean
    public MongoCustomConversions customConversions() {
        List<Converter<?, ?>> converters = new ArrayList<>();
        converters.add(new DateToZonedDateTimeConverter());
        converters.add(new ZonedDateTimeToDateConverter());
        return new MongoCustomConversions(converters);
    }

    class DateToZonedDateTimeConverter implements Converter<Date, ZonedDateTime> {

        @Override
        public ZonedDateTime convert(Date source) {
            return source == null ? null : 
                    ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(source.toInstant(), ZoneId.systemDefault());
        }
    }

    class ZonedDateTimeToDateConverter implements Converter<ZonedDateTime, Date> {

        @Override
        public Date convert(ZonedDateTime source) {
            return source == null ? null : Date.from(source.toInstant());
        }
    }
}
```

---

I wouldn't, however, use [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) for this purpose. I would stick to [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html):

> [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html), [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) and [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) all store an instant on the time-line to nanosecond precision. Instant is the simplest, simply representing the instant. [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) adds to the instant the offset from UTC/Greenwich, which allows the local date-time to be obtained. [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) adds full time-zone rules.
>
> It is intended that [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) or [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) is used to model data in simpler applications. This class may be used when modeling date-time concepts in more detail, or when communicating to a database or in a network protocol.

Comment: Works perfectly.

Comment: @cassiomolin When using these customConversions you loose precision, since as you said: OffsetDateTime, ZoneDateTime and Instant are nanosecond precision, but Date is only millisecond. The consequence is that persisting e.g. a ZonedDateTime and then reading it again, results in objects not being equal.

Comment: This is true. The nanoseconds precision is lost after save/retrieve. This is why in my DateTimeProvider I trim the precision to milliseconds.
`Optional.of(ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC))
        .map(now -> now.withNano((now.getNano() / 1_000_000) * 1_000_000))`