# @CreatedBy and @LastModifiedDate are no longer working with ZonedDateTime?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, zoneddatetime

i have updated an old spring boot 1.5.3 project to spring boot 2.0.0. RELEASE. 
I have an auditing entity with two fields of type ZonedDateTime annotated with @CreatedBy and @LastModifiedDate.

In the previous versions everything was working fine. However,  with the new update, upon saving the entity in the repository i get an error i.e

```
 createdDate=<null>
 lastModifiedDate=<null>
 ]! Supported types are [org.joda.time.DateTime, org.joda.time.LocalDateTime, java.util.Date, java.lang.Long, long]
```

I checked the [AnnotationAuditingMetaData](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-commons/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/auditing/AnnotationAuditingMetadata.java), and i found noting related to ZonedDateTime.

There is also this issue in https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1242, I believe it's related.

My question is what am i doing wrong here, does spring stopped the support or am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old answer was mistaken, but I can't delete it because it is accepted. **Please scroll to other answers.**

Comment: It' doens't work for me. Is there any other solutions?

Comment: jackson has nothing to do with JPA

Answer (score 38):

I had the same problem and could solve it adding a `dateTimeProviderRef` to `@EnableJpaAuditing`.

**Java**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.auditing.DateTimeProvider;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaAuditing;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.util.Optional;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing(dateTimeProviderRef = "auditingDateTimeProvider")
public class PersistenceConfig {

    @Bean // Makes ZonedDateTime compatible with auditing fields
    public DateTimeProvider auditingDateTimeProvider() {
        return () -> Optional.of(ZonedDateTime.now());
    }

}
```

**Kotlin**

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaAuditing(dateTimeProviderRef = "auditingDateTimeProvider")
class PersistenceConfig {

    @Bean // Makes ZonedDateTime compatible with auditing fields
    fun auditingDateTimeProvider()= DateTimeProvider { of(ZonedDateTime.now()) }

}
```

Comment: Facing this error : org.bson.codecs.configuration.CodecConfigurationException: Can't find a codec for class java.time.ZonedDateTime.
Did you face the same issue? I'm with Java, MongoDB.

Comment: @NguyễnĐứcTâm You also need to register the converters for ZonedDateTime, like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51664363/4245733

Comment: still doesn't work for me. I use Instant type though.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to  put this annotation
`@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)`
on the class where you use the `@CreatedDate`.