# How to save String type date to mongoDB without it to be converted?

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I have a java POJO with string type date `"2022-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"`. When I save it to mongodb, it converts to `"Fri Dec 31 16:00:00 PST 2021"` format. How can keep the original format?

Comment: The answer you are looking for is here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23972002/java-8-date-time-jsr-310-types-mapping-with-spring-data-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

Do you set the field type as String?
Test this.
This must be working correctly for you.

```
public class Person{
   ...
   private String dateStringFormat;
}
```